# Unable to retrieve right values

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am unable to retrieve values on this code.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

contract Storage{
    int number;
    function storePositive(int256 nump) public{
        number = nump;
    }
    function storeNegative(int256 numn) public{
        number = -numn;
    }
    function retreivep() public view returns(int256){
        return number;
    }
    function retreiven() public view returns(int256){
        return number;
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve separate values for positive and negative numbers stored. All it is showing me is
`0:int256: 0` on both retrievep and retrieven.
P.S. This is my first ever Solidity code, so please explain on an elementary level.

Comment: Are you calling store methods transactionally?

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite know what does storing methods transactionally mean yet. I have been following a tutorial and they did it till defining funtions `storePositive` and `storeNegative` but the number as `number=1234` for positive and `number = -1234` for negative. But with only one retreive function
 `function retrieve() public view returns(int256){
        return number;
    }`
I wanted to be flexible and wanted to store whatever I type in and retrieve them separately. So I tried to make it like this.
I hope it clears the point of making this as I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: To change the state of the contract, the method must be called via a transaction (eth_sendTransaction or similar in web3). When the method is "viewed" (eth_call or similar in web 3), no changes will be recorded.